# How to define the css for the four DIV in web hompage

Tags: html, css

In my project, I have a webpage.

For the web homepage, I want to divide the it into four parts between header and footer.

the core code of homepage is like:

```html
<body style="background:url(./image/taiyi.jpg); height:100%; width:100%;">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#header").load("header_02.html");
        });
    </script>
    <div class="upleft"></div>
    <div class="upright"></div>
    <div class="downleft"></div>
    <div class="downright"></div>

    <!--footer start-->
    <div id="footer"></div>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#footer").load("../footer_02.html");
        });
    </script>
    <!--footer end-->
</body>
```

The code of footer_02.html is like:

```html
<style>
    .footer {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 9;
        font-size: 13px;
    }
</style>
<div class="footer w100 ">
    <div class="w1100 mc cb">
        <p>Cel：0xxx-8xxxx1531&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;address：John street&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;poster：518055&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;E-mail:h@su.xxx.com&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&copy;research center</p>
        <div class="contact">
            <p><a href="../introduction/job.html" target="_blank">employee</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="../map.html" target="_blank">contact us</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;joke me：</p><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="weixin"><span></span></a><a href="../map.html" target="_blank" class="map"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, I want to define the four parts: upleft, upright, downleft, downright. They are floating the taiyi.jpg, and I can define the size.But I don't know how to define CSS for each them

They have the same size. Who can give me a favor?

Comment: What have you already tried? The CSS could be defined in more than one way depending upon your preferences or the needs of the project

Answer (score 1):

you have to add some more CSS styles such as you already done with footer

```
 <style>
  .upleft, .downleft{
    width: 50%;
    height: 250px;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
  }
  .upright, .downright{
    width: 50%;
    height: 250px;
    float: right;
    clear: right;
  }
</style>
```

By this way you shuld have your homepage divided 4 rectangles
It's better to add **clear** attributes for both style classes.

Comment: .upleft, .downleft have overlapped together!!

Answer (score 0):

Just add a class in every div then insert a specified style for that class that can being reused by other divs, take a look at this code below

```
<body style="background:url(./image/taiyi.jpg); height:100%; width:100%;">
  <div id="header"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $("#header").load("header_02.html");
    });
  </script>
  <div class="upleft specifiedSize"></div>
  <div class="upright specifiedSize"></div>
  <div class="downleft specifiedSize"></div>
  <div class="downright specifiedSize"></div>

  <!--footer start-->
  <div id="footer"></div>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $("#footer").load("../footer_02.html");
   });
  </script>
  <!--footer end-->
</body>
```

Then add the .specifiedSize to your styling tag

```
<style>
  .footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 9;
    font-size: 13px;
  }
 .specifiedSize {
    font-size: 20px; //example size
  }
</style>
```